# How to write out an hr tag programatically in .net

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to programtically write out an h1 tag in .net. I'm sure I've done this in the past but cannot remember how its done. I thought there was a property of the label class where the output tag could be changed.

Comment: `hr` as your title states or `h1` as your questions states?

Comment: if you have done this previously try to remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Literal` control and set it to `PassThrough` mode. This is the easiest way for the `hr` tag

```
Literal myTag = new Literal {Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough, Text = "<hr/>"};
```

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx)

---

If you are creating an `h1` tag then you should use this

```
HtmlContainerControl myTag = (HtmlContainerControl)new HtmlGenericControl("h1");
```

This will allow you to add controls to the contents of the tag.

---

You shouldn't use the standard `HtmlGenericControl` for the `hr` tag because the implementation doesn't allow tag self-closing. The `hr` tag would be written as `<hr></hr>` instead of `<hr/>`. But you can make it self closing with a little work, by overriding the control. [See here for details](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/aspnetcontrols/a-self-closing-htmlgenericcontrol)